# Sharing using vkontakte, odnoklassniki, kaixinrepaste

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an iphone application in which i need to share images to to the below social networks.
1) vkontakte, 
2) odnoklassniki, 
3) kaixinrepaste

I dont get any ideas where to start. Do anyone have some ideas? Or Is there anything available like Sharekit for these social networks?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/gpinigin/GPActivityViewController  - Here you can find the customised alternative to UIActivityViewController including Vkontakte and Odnoklassniki activities

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/maiorov/VKAPI - here is some sample, how to share images, text, etc. For vk.com